# Get a parameter from URL and add it to iframe src

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am looking for a simple way (using JavaScript) to get part of the page URL to be added to the end of the iframe src URL.

Example, page URL: [www.example.com/?id=XYZ](http://www.example.com/?id=XYZ)

Then I need the XYZ part, which is the the ID to be added to the iframe src like so:

And iframe src: [www.otheradress.com/XYZ](http://www.otheradress.com/XYZ)

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far. maybe some javascript example. where you are adding that iframe ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the query string from your route with `window.location.search` (only what comes after the '?', included), and you can parse the parameters with the URLSearchParams like this `const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);`.

After that, `params` is an object with specific methods, and you can obtain your param by name with `params.get('id');`.

So you only need to concatenate your base URL and this parameter and pass it to the `src` attribute of the iframe.

Complete example:

```
const baseIframeUrl = 'www.otheradress.com/';
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
document.getElementById('#yourIframe').src = baseIframeUrl . urlParams.get('id');
```

If you wanted to use the src attribute from the HTML, it would be:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
document.getElementById('#yourIframe').src = document.getElementById('#yourIframe').src . urlParams.get('id');
```

Though be aware that this approach would fail when called multiple times unless you store somewhere the original URL.
Also, as pointed out by mplungjan, you cannot access the `src` of an iframe of another origin.

Comment: You cannot get the src of an iFrame of another origin

Comment: Also `www.otheraddress.com ` is not a valid URL without a protocol

Comment: Yep, that's just taken from his example code, I don't think that needs clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and URLSearchParams

NOTE: You cannot READ the iFrame src from an iframe that has loaded a page from another origin for security reasons

```js
const url = new URL("https://www.example.com/?id=XYZ"); // new URL(location.href);
const id = url.searchParams.get("id")
console.log(id)
const iFrameUrl = new URL("https://www.otheradress.com/")
iFrameUrl.pathname+=id;
console.log(iFrameUrl.toString()); // here you can set the source of the iFrame
```